# Default selected button in html form

Tags: html

I'm making a form for a ticking site and can't figure out how to have a button selected by default.

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="general"> General<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="medium"> Medium<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="high"> High
</form>
```

I know it's something simple but I can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a checked attribute into the input tag like so.

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="general" checked> General<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="medium"> Medium<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="high"> High
</form>
```

see [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the [`checked`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) attribute to the relevant input.

> The checked attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that an  element should be pre-selected (checked) when the page loads.

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="general" checked> General<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="medium"> Medium<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="high"> High
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `checked` attribute.

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="general" checked> General<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="medium"> Medium<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="high"> High
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "checked" attribute in input where you want to check.

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="general" checked> General<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="medium"> Medium<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="high"> High
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Checked` attribute of **HTML** `input` tag:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="general"> General<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="medium"> Medium<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="high" checked> High
</form>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shishirmax/c4daczbp/)